# Seaborn FacetGrid PointPlot Label Data Points

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

Given the following:

```
import seaborn as sns
attend = sns.load_dataset("attention")
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False,'axes.edgecolor':'none'})
g = sns.FacetGrid(attend, col="subject", col_wrap=5,
size=1.5, ylim=(0, 10))
ax = g.map(sns.pointplot, "solutions", "score", scale=.7)
```

I would like to label individual data points (put value labels in place of dots) on each line. In another plot that I created via MatPlotLib only, this was accomplished like this:

```
for i, text in enumerate(ind):
    a.annotate(str(y[i])[:-2], xy=(ind[i], y[i]),fontsize=6, color=c, 
                bbox=dict(pad=.9,alpha=1, fc='white',color='none'),va='center', ha='center',weight='bold')
```

However, since there is no ind defined, I'm not sure how this would work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't know what `ind` is either. But if the aim is to annotate the points with their coordinates, you may use `ax.annotate` inside a function that is mapped to the `FacetGrid` as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

attend = sns.load_dataset("attention")
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False,'axes.edgecolor':'none'})
g = sns.FacetGrid(attend, col="subject", col_wrap=5,
                  size=1.5, ylim=(0, 10))

def f(x,y, **kwargs):
    ax = sns.pointplot(x,y,**kwargs)
    ax.axhline(5, alpha=0.5, color='grey')
    for i in range(len(x)):
        ax.annotate(str(y.values[i]), xy=(x.values[i]-1, y.values[i]),fontsize=8,
                    xytext = (0,10), textcoords="offset points",
                color=kwargs.get("color","k"), 
                bbox=dict(pad=.9,alpha=0.2, fc='limegreen',color='none'),
                va='center', ha='center',weight='bold')

g.map(f, "solutions", "score", scale=.7)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Possibly, you need to use `xy=(i, y.values[i])` in the annotation, depending on what the data looks like.

Note that this also answers [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848281/seaborn-facetgrid-pointplot-add-1-grid-line) by putting the `axhline` in that function as well.

If the aim is to replace the points by the annotations, use `xytext = (0,0)` or leave that argument out completely; then also keep `bbox=dict(pad=.9,alpha=1, fc='w',color='none')` and use `markers=""` in the function call:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

attend = sns.load_dataset("attention")
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False,'axes.edgecolor':'none'})
g = sns.FacetGrid(attend, col="subject", col_wrap=5,
                  size=1.5, ylim=(0, 10))

def f(x,y, **kwargs):
    ax = sns.pointplot(x,y,**kwargs)
    ax.axhline(5, alpha=0.5, color='grey')
    for i in range(len(x)):
        ax.annotate(str(y.values[i]), xy=(i, y.values[i]),fontsize=8,
                color=kwargs.get("color","k"), 
                bbox=dict(pad=.9,alpha=1, fc='w',color='none'),
                va='center', ha='center',weight='bold')

g.map(f, "solutions", "score", scale=.7, markers="")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I'm assuming using xy=(i, y.values[i]) in the annotation will allow me to replace the dots with the actual values, so long as I have a box around it.

Comment: I may have misunderstood you. The updated answer may then be more what you want.