# How to add labels on facetgrid barplot in seaborn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.DataFrame({'reg': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'file': ['1', '1', '2'],
                   'val': [1, 2, 3]})
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='file', hue='reg', col_wrap=3)
g.map(sns.barplot, 'reg', 'val',  order=df.reg.unique()).add_legend()
g.savefig('test_so.png')
```

How can I add the numbers of `val` on top of the bars ?

**UPDATE**

This questions differs from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214978/seaborn-barplot-displaying-values) because that solution does not work with facetgrid

Comment: The quesiton that you linked does not have any information regarding facetgrid. Please remove the duplicate

Comment: Please refer to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849028/seaborn-facetgrid-pointplot-label-data-points.

Comment: This solution works for me for facetgrid. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51535326/560821. Saves me a lot of time. I agree with @quant. This is not a duplicate query